# Haskell: Check if the name in a list

Tags: haskell

I have the question for checking if there is this name in a list haskell.I have written this program,but when I check it work,butwhen I Check there is not any answer.If someone can help me?

```
db = [("David","worksfor", "IBM")
 ,("Alan","takeinterhipin", "Microsoft")
checkIfElem :: String -> [String] -> Bool
checkIfElem "David" db = if "David" `elem` db 
                         then True
                       else False
```

The error is in the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QKpf.png)

Comment: Please give us the error message or unexpected vs expected input. Is this code in a file or are you in ghci?

Comment: did you notice that `db` is not `[String]`?

Comment: I am the beginner,if you can give me some suggestions?TKS

Comment: Aside: please avoid the anti-pattern `if condition then True else False`. This is equivalent to `condition`, only longer. E.g. `positive x = (x > 0)` is simpler than `positive x = if x > 0 then True else False`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because your function `checkIfElem` expected `db` to be a `String`, but is instead receiving a list of tuples (or triples).

Here's your code reformatted a bit:

```
db = [ ("David","worksfor", "IBM")
     , ("Alan","takeinterhipin", "Microsoft")
     ]
checkIfElem :: String -> [String] -> Bool
checkIfElem "David" db =
    if "David" `elem` db then True else False
```

Since `("David", "worksfor", "IBM")` has the type of `(String, String, String)`, your code does not type-check.  You can fix this by introducing a function to extract the name portion of this type, which is just a string.  Here's the code with this function in use:

```
db = [ ("David","worksfor", "IBM")
     , ("Alan","takeinterhipin", "Microsoft")
     ]
checkIfElem :: String -> [(String, String, String)] -> Bool
checkIfElem "David" db =
    if "David" `elem` (map getName db) then True else False

getName :: (String, String, String) -> String
getName (name, _, _) = name
```

Notice the `getName` function, takes a tuple and returns a `String`.  To use this, we also had to update the type of `checkIfElem`. to take a list of tuples for the type of `db` (the second argument to your function).

Running your function with "David" now works as you can see here:

```
*Main> checkIfElem "David" db
True
```

This still isn't right though, since any other name will cause a runtime error:

```
*Main> checkIfElem "Jim" db
*** Exception: foo.hs:(7,1)-(8,59): Non-exhaustive patterns in function checkIfElem
```

This is because you are pattern-matching on "David" as the first argument.  You haven't defined your function for any other value.  The name is passed when you call the function, after all, so you don't really need to include "David" in the definition of the function itself.

Replacing the string `"David"` to some lower-cased variable name in your function definition, like `name` will fix that problem for you, and your function should work as you expect from there.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it was correct, ada?